# How do I get the x-axis of a matplotlib histogram to display correctly when the series is time?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

The data involved in this problem looks like this:

```
 df2['Time Of Stop'].head()

 138593    13:00:00
 681234    03:19:00
 521404    02:38:00
 183703    01:33:00
 715512    21:29:00
 Name: Time Of Stop, dtype: object
```

Then plotting was done with:

```
 f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(9,6))
 ax.hist(df2['Time Of Stop'], bins =10)
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

Notice that the x-axis labels is just a black strip. How does one fix this?

PS: Histograms of normal numpy arrays display correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is currently of string/object type. You need to convert it into a datetime object and then it would be plotted correctly. You can do this using the `pd.to_datetime` method

```
a="""
138593    13:00:00
 681234    03:19:00
 521404    02:38:00
 183703    01:33:00
 715512    21:29:00
"""



df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(a),sep="\s+", header = None)
df.columns = ['index','Time']

#Converting the string variable to a time object
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
df.Time = df.Time.apply( lambda x : pd.Timestamp(x).time())

f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(9,6))
ax.hist(df.Time, bins =10)
```

The output looks like
[image]

Comment: I get `TypeError: invalid type promotion`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `plt.xticks(rotation=90)` to your code / plot.

Or convert to datetime first.

```
df2['Time Of Stop'] = df2['Time Of Stop'].astype("datetime64")
df2.groupby(df2["Time Of Stop"].dt.hour).count().plot(kind="bar")
```